# Create an AWS HTTP API as resource in serverless

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless, serverless-architecture

How can I create an HTTP API with serverless framework so I can manage it in my .yml file? The documentations shows this:

```
functions:
  testFunc:
    name: lambdaName
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /v1/test
          method: get
```

That would create the api but dependant on the function, how can I create the API here to configure it and use it on the function?

I want to be able to manage it on my .yml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. When a new lambda function is created using `serverless framework` you can define the API type as shown above in my question. Now since the stack is expecting that type I can also modify it in my globals (aka provider), and even use the id to share the resource across other lambda functions, for example:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
  stage: v1 
  region: us-east-1 # <- This is your regeion, make sure it is or change it
  httpApi:
    # id: xxx 
    payload: "2.0" 
    name: "v1-my-service"
    cors: false
```

Comment: can i use existing resource path as well? @ElkePoN